# The use of "horizontally gifted"

Tags: expressions, political-correctness

> **horizontally gifted**:
>
> *A **politically correct** way of calling someone fat*

Can `horizontally gifted` still be offensive? Or is it an absolutely safe way to describe someone overweight if we have to find the right words to do it, without hurting anyone?

Comment: It sounds like derision to me.

Comment: I’ve heard that *plump* is a less hurtful term than *fat*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is absolutely sarcasm rather than polite or politically correct. Don’t use it.